# Subclass UICollectionViewCell in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

Given the following `UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
class MJCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var MJImageView: UIImageView!
    var image = UIImage()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // MARK: - Setters

    func setImage(image: UIImage) {
        self.MJImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

I receive the following error on `func setImage(image: UIImage)`:

```
Method 'setImage' redeclares Objective-C method 'setImage:'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rename the methond `setImage(image: UIImage)`, because there is already a method with this name declared in the Objective-C's `UICollectionViewCell` class.